# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'am learning spring boot and I am creating a project that take data from a JSON and put them in a database .While trying to create the GET methods I had this exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'userController' method
```

here is my controller . I will be happy if someone can help .. Thank you !

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@GetMapping("/data")
public List<User> getUsers(){

    List<User> usersFinal = userService.getUsers();

    return usersFinal;
}



public String save50User(User user) {
    List<User> usersFinal = userService.getUsers();
    for(int i = 0;i<50;i++) {
        userService.saveUser(usersFinal.get(i));
    }

    return " the first 50 users saved";
}


@GetMapping("/user/{title}")
public List<User> showByTitle(@PathVariable String title) {
    List<User> s = userService.showByTitleLike(title);
    return s;
}


@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
public List<User> showByUserId(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    List<User> s =  userService.showByUserId(id);
    return s;
}


@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
public User showById(@PathVariable int id) {
    User s = userService.showById(id);
    return s;
}
@GetMapping("/user/{completed}")
public List<User> showCompletedTrue(@PathVariable boolean bool) {
    List<User> s = userService.showByCompleted(bool);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: This `@GetMapping("/user/{id}")` mapping exists twice. That is not going to work.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes I got it ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but all your Get Endpoints are ambiguous all having the same pattern which does not make them distinct

Means

```
@GetMapping("/user/{title}")
@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
@GetMapping("/user/{completed}")
```

If you call the **/user/xyz**, It won't recognise which endpoint needs to be called and which code needs to be executed because **xyz can title, id or completed**

So to make it distinct you should change the url pattern like

```
@GetMapping("/user/title/{title}")
@GetMapping("/user/id/{id}")
@GetMapping("/user/completed/{completed}")
```

this will make the endpoints distinct and your expected business logic would be executed

Comment: Thank you so much ! It is working .. This is my first application using @Query with parameters that's why I was'nt able to get that problem